# count distinct in SAS SQL case when

Tags: sql, sas

I have a data set

```
Outlet    Period     Brand    Sales
A          Jan         XX       12
A          Jan         XY       13
A          FEB         AB       10
B          JAN         AC       19
```

I would like to count the number of distinct brands for each period within each period, but excluding a brand 'CD'. I would like to inquire does the count distinct not work in a single line as shown below, but would only work on example 2?

Example 1 (Brand CD is counted even though it should not be)

```
PROC SQL;
      CREATE TABLE Test AS 
            SELECT      
                  Outlet, Period, Brand,

              case when Brand not in ('CD') then count (distinct Brand)  end as k_Brands_Players2

       group by period, outlet;
quit;
```

Example 2 (Brand CD is correctly not counted)

```
PROC SQL;
      CREATE TABLE Test AS 
            SELECT      
                  Outlet, Period, Brand,

              case when Brand not in ('CD') then Brand else ' ' end as Brand_Players, 
              count(distinct calculated Brand_Players) as k_Brands_Players


       group by period, outlet;
quit;
```

The expected output is:

```
Outlet     Period     Brand     k_Brands_Players
  A          Jan        XX            2
  A          Jan        XY            2
  A          Feb        AS            3
  A          FEB        QW            3
  A          Feb        XY            3
  B          Jan        KW            1
  ....
```

Comment: What is expected output from your data set ?

Comment: I have just added it, thank you for reminding!

Comment: Your posted data does not have any records with brand='CD'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
/*Count distinct will come outside the case when statement*/

PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE Test AS 
  SELECT distinct Outlet, Period, Brand, k_Brands_Players
  from
  YOUR_DATASET_NAME a
  LEFT JOIN
  (
        SELECT      
              Outlet, Period, 

          count(distinct(case when Brand not in ('CD') then Brand end)) as k_Brands_Players

        FROM YOUR_DATASET_NAME
   group by 1,2
  ) b
  on a.Outlet=b.Outlet and a.Period=b.Period;
quit;
```

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: edited the query to get in line with the output required

Comment: Thanks it works! But can I know  what leads to the error in the first example?

Comment: My earlier query was not giving Brand name in the output. Changed it to get that

Comment: In your first query you put count distinct inside the case when. Instead it should have been outside. In your second query, you cannot count or do some some operation on a column which is newly formed and not existing in the table

Comment: *deleted* comment was Answered

Comment: @user90831 because "case when Brand not in ('CD') then count (distinct Brand)" , so its not doing what you are intending to do. Also, if you are using Brand in select statement before the aggregated function count, then it should be in group by also

Comment: Anyways if you put Brand in group by then you won't get the right answer

Comment: @India.Rocket This is correct, but this answer would be much better with more actual explanation - see Tom's answer for example which is much more along the lines of what we expect on this site.

Comment: @Joe it's in the comment section. Question changed a bit in between and thus the explanation which I had given had to change. I got the understanding of what exactly user wanted and gave user all explanation in comments (you can see them in comments) post him/her asking the questions around it. Agreed, I should have also posted it with solution. But It was fun and I enjoyed it. I believe, on the spot conversations always lead to better explanations and user satisfaction. But again views can differ across persons. Anyways, thanks for pointing it out. Will keep this in my mind

Comment: @India.Rocket That comment by itself isn't really enough, though- I did see that.  First, comments aren't the right place for that - I don't think there's a SO style guide, but it would be pretty high up.  We use Markdown for a reason, and one of those reasons is it lets you do this in a much more readable way.  But moreover, you should give more information about why it doesn't work - again, see how Tom did exactly the same thing.  That's what we want to see here.  It's fine for things to evolve in comments, but the answer should also include that.

Comment: @Joe I think the idea behind a solution/comment in SO is not code-only, but explains the how - teaches, not gives. I understand that. I think I did that and I am satisfied with that. As I said, I will keep your feedback in my mind for future. Thanks again:-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your first query is that you are using the COUNT() aggregate function at the wrong place. You have

```
case when Brand not in ('CD') then count(distinct Brand) end
```

So when BRAND is equal to 'CD' you will get a missing value and otherwise you will get the number of distinct Brands, including the 'CD' Brand.

If instead you use this construction:

```
count(distinct case when Brand not in ('CD') then Brand end)
```

then the COUNT() function will see the 'CD' value as a missing value and not count it.